# add regex to stop words in spacy

Tags: spacy, stop-words

is there a way we can add regex patters to stop words in SPACY or NLTK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regular expressions are patterns used to match character combinations in strings. So I think for recognizing SPACY or NLTK, we need many specified case to map pattern.

Comment: I wanted to stop a perticular pattern in the using stop words in spacy. for example if I want to remove all the emails using stop words, will it be possible?